# Why are different instances of the same class overwriting each other?

Tags: javascript, class

So my problem lies in playAI and in  miniMaxAlgorithm.

To start off, I make a copy of the instance myTicTacToe which I call tempgame afterwards I call miniMaxAlgorithm on that copy. All this to make sure myTicTacToe stays unchanged.

The problem though is myTicTacToe  has afterwards the same values as tempgame.
I don't understand why.

/**************************TicTacToe Class**********************/

```
class TicTacToe {




constructor(playField = [

    ['E', 'E', 'E'],
    ['E', 'E', 'E'],
    ['E', 'E', 'E']


], human = 'X', computer = 'O', gameStatus = "playing", currentPlayer = 'X') {

    this.playField = playField;


    this.human = human;
    this.computer = computer;
    this.gameStatus = gameStatus;
    this.bestMove;
    this.startingPlayer = human;


    this.currentPlayer = currentPlayer;

}



reset() {
    this.playField = [

        ['E', 'E', 'E'],
        ['E', 'E', 'E'],
        ['E', 'E', 'E']


    ];

    this.gameStatus = 'playing';
    this.currentPlayer = this.startingPlayer;
    $('#gamestate').text('');

}


checkGameState() {

    /******************** Win conditions******************************/
    if (this.currentPlayer === 'X' || this.currentPlayer === 'O') {

        if (this.winOrNot()) {


            $('#gamestate').text('Player ' + this.currentPlayer + ' won.');
            this.gameStatus = 'over';

        }



        //********************** Check if it is a draw***************/
        else {
            /*which results in a draw*/
            let arrayOfFreePlaces = this.freePositions();
            if (!(arrayOfFreePlaces.length > 0)) {

                $('#gamestate').text('It is a draw');
                this.gameStatus = 'over';
            }

        }

    }
}
/***********************/

winOrNot() {

    if ((this.playField[0][0] === this.currentPlayer && this.playField[0][1] === this.currentPlayer && this.playField[0][2] === this.currentPlayer) ||
        (this.playField[1][0] === this.currentPlayer && this.playField[1][1] === this.currentPlayer && this.playField[1][2] === this.currentPlayer) ||
        (this.playField[2][0] === this.currentPlayer && this.playField[2][1] === this.currentPlayer && this.playField[2][2] === this.currentPlayer) ||
        (this.playField[0][0] === this.currentPlayer && this.playField[1][0] === this.currentPlayer && this.playField[2][0] === this.currentPlayer) ||
        (this.playField[0][1] === this.currentPlayer && this.playField[1][1] === this.currentPlayer && this.playField[2][1] === this.currentPlayer) ||
        (this.playField[0][2] === this.currentPlayer && this.playField[1][2] === this.currentPlayer && this.playField[2][2] === this.currentPlayer) ||
        (this.playField[0][0] === this.currentPlayer && this.playField[1][1] === this.currentPlayer && this.playField[2][2] === this.currentPlayer) ||
        (this.playField[0][2] === this.currentPlayer && this.playField[1][1] === this.currentPlayer && this.playField[2][0] === this.currentPlayer)

    ) {

        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}


freePositions() {

    let emptyPositions = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < this.playField.length; i++) {




        for (let j = 0; j < this.playField[i].length; j++) {

            if (this.playField[i][j] === 'E') {


                emptyPositions.push([i, j]);


            }



        }



    }



    return emptyPositions;



}
// rate gamestate

rateField() {
    // if computer wins +10
    if (this.winOrNot(this.computer)) {

        return 10;
    }
    // if human wins -10
    else if (this.winOrNot(this.human)) {

        return -10;
    }
    // if no one wins +0, aka drawm or not finished yet
    else {

        return 0;

    }


}




}

  //Prototypes of TicTacToe


   TicTacToe.prototype.placeSign = function(row, column) {
   // check if field is empty

if (this.playField[row][column] === 'E') {

    if (this.currentPlayer === "X") {


        this.playField[row][column] = 'X';

    } else if (this.currentPlayer === "O") {

        this.playField[row][column] = 'O';

    }
    this.checkGameState();
    this.currentPlayer === this.computer ? this.currentPlayer = this.human : this.currentPlayer = this.computer;


} else {


    console.log("Select an empty field!!");
}
```

};

/*******************Declarations*******************************/

```
    let myTicTacToe = new TicTacToe();
     let tempgame = new TicTacToe();
       let bestMove;
```

/*****************Functions*************************/

// miniMaxAlgorithm

```
  function miniMaxAlgorithm(TicTacToe1) {








/****************base case********************************/

// if the game is over , return rating
if (TicTacToe1.gameStatus === 'over') {
    return TicTacToe1.rateField();
}
/******************************************/
//contains the rating of each move
let scores = [];

// containing the equivalent moves
let moves = [];

//fill the scores array
/**************************recursive case*******************************/
// create on array with containing all possible moves of the current tictactoe instance
let freeFields = TicTacToe1.freePositions();
for (let i = 0; i < freeFields.length; i++) {
    //make a copy of the current tictactoe instance
    let possibleTicTacToe = new TicTacToe(TicTacToe1.playField, TicTacToe1.human, TicTacToe1.computer, TicTacToe1.gameStatus, TicTacToe1.currentPlayer);
    //play one of the possible moves
    possibleTicTacToe.placeSign(freeFields[i][0], freeFields[i][1]);
    // calling the function recursively until game is over 
    scores.push(miniMaxAlgorithm(possibleTicTacToe));
    // adding place sign parameters ass an array inside moves
    moves.push([freeFields[i][0], freeFields[i][1]]);
}


//  Min Max Calculation
if (TicTacToe1.currentPlayer === TicTacToe1.computer) {
    //      search for the largest score and save its index in maxScoreIndex
    let maxScoreIndex = 0;
    for (let j = 1; j < scores.length; j++) {
        if (scores[j] > scores[maxScoreIndex]) {
            maxScoreIndex = j;

        }

    }

    bestMove = moves[maxScoreIndex];
    return scores[maxScoreIndex];
}

// tests best possible opponent moves (human)
else {
    //        
    let minScoreIndex = 0;
    for (let j = 1; j < scores.length; j++) {
        if (scores[j] < scores[minScoreIndex]) {
            minScoreIndex = j;

        }



    }




    bestMove = moves[minScoreIndex];
    return scores[minScoreIndex];
}



/**********************************************************************/
```

}

function updateFields() {

```
document.getElementById('field1').innerHTML = myTicTacToe.playField[0][0];
document.getElementById('field2').innerHTML = myTicTacToe.playField[0][1];
document.getElementById('field3').innerHTML = myTicTacToe.playField[0][2];
document.getElementById('field4').innerHTML = myTicTacToe.playField[1][0];
document.getElementById('field5').innerHTML = myTicTacToe.playField[1][1];
document.getElementById('field6').innerHTML = myTicTacToe.playField[1][2];
document.getElementById('field7').innerHTML = myTicTacToe.playField[2][0];
document.getElementById('field8').innerHTML = myTicTacToe.playField[2][1];
document.getElementById('field9').innerHTML = myTicTacToe.playField[2][2];
           }
          /**********************************************************/
```

//playAI

```
 function playAI() {

//AI miniMaxEnd

    tempgame = new TicTacToe (myTicTacToe.playField,myTicTacToe.human,myTicTacToe.computer,myTicTacToe.gameStatus,myTicTacToe.currentPlayer)

         console.dir(myTicTacToe);
        console.dir(tempgame);
         miniMaxAlgorithm(tempgame);
         console.dir(myTicTacToe);
         console.dir(tempgame);

    myTicTacToe.placeSign(bestMove[0],bestMove[1]);
  //AI miniMaxEnd




updateFields();

}
```

Comment: `tempGame = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myTicTacToe));` this will make a copy of `myTicTacToe` and assign it to `tempGame`

Comment: Only works for the properties. Doesn't copy the prototype functions of the class

Comment: Is it ok if you used jQuery?

Comment: I don't understand. How do I use jQuery on a class instance.

Comment: Try [$.extend()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

Comment: This solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Nvm still not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an idea as to what may be causing this issue.

In javascript arrays (or lists) are passed by *reference* rather than *value*.

What this means that if you pass a function an array as a parameter it will pass a *pointer to* the list rather than a *copy of* the list.

In your **TicTacToe** class you have a variable called **playField** that is a  list.

You create a clone of the TicTacToe object like this:

```
tempgame = new TicTacToe (myTicTacToe.playField, ... )
```

Here you are *passing a reference* to the existing *playField* list rather than cloning the list.  i.e. Passing the address of the list rather than its contents.

Both your *myTicTacToe* and *tempgame* will use the **same copy** of the *playField* data.  A change in one will cause a change in the other.

In order to create a *new copy* of the array it is standard to use the javascript **slice** operation:

```
tempgame = new TicTacToe (myTicTacToe.playField.slice(0), ... )
```

This operation will create a fresh copy of the array starting at the first element (0).

More information on using the slice operation to clone an array can be found here:

https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-clone-array

Comment: Cloning objects with javascript can be tricky.  Someone ran into a similar problem here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002946/javascript-oop-classes-multiple-instances-share-same-data

Comment: ok finally found the solution you were pretty close. The problem with my code is that I have nested arrays in my class.  This means even if I clone the outer array, the inner arrays have still the same reference. Read it here https://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-clone-a-nested-array-in-javascript/

Comment: Cool! Glad you figured it out.  I wouldn't have considered that nested arrays needed nested slicing but I suppose it makes sense.